# How to improve performance for large lists in python

Tags: python, performance, list, optimization

I have a large list with say 10 million of integers (sorted) "alist". What I need is to get the smallest distance between some of the integers (from a "blist") and the neighbours in the list. I do it by finding the position of the integer I look for, get the item before and after and measure the difference:

```
alist=[1, 4, 30, 1000, 2000] #~10 million integers
blist=[4, 30, 1000] #~8 million integers

for b in blist:
    position=alist.index(b)
    distance=min([b-alist[position-1],alist[position+1]-b])
```

This operation has to be repeated millions of times and, unfortunately, it takes ages on my machine. Is there a way to improve performance of this code? I use python 2.6 and python 3 is not an option.

Comment: Any reason why you're using Python for a CPU intensive operation? Can you rewrite that part of the code in C and interface it with Python?

Comment: You're using Python 2.6 on a personal computer, with **in-memory** lists of a huge size (10^7), performing an O(n) operation **millions of times** using built-in methods without any algorithmic optimization. What kind of performance are you expecting, exactly?

Comment: What @VincentSavard said. Alternatively, it sounds like you could vectorize your algorithm and use numpy, so that the actual code runs in very smart C/Fortran code. The minimum distance between each value in vector `v` (where `type(v)==np.array`) and its neighbor is given by `np.amin(v[1:] - v[:-1])`. Adapt this to whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Try turning `alist` into a dict to avoid the O(n) indexing operation. `alist = dict(enumerate(alist))`.

Comment: Not sure how many processor cores you are working with...is threading an option or do you purely need a refactoring solution? I don't know how much improvement you are going to get though (in any case) in this situation. As Two-bit Alchemist implies, this is a large operation for what sounds like a PC setup.

Comment: @VincentSavard :) if I could write in C I would not have asked this kind of questions... I am just a biologist here.

Comment: @Rawing How do I find previous and next item in dictionary, than?

Comment: You can't avoid looping through all values of `b`, but as Rawing said, you could change your algorithm from `O(n*m)` to `O(n)` if you used a different data structure for `a`, probably at the cost of a higher memory consumption. You could either duplicate `a` in a dict to map the value to an index, or you could possibly use an ordered set.

Comment: You could also try _not_ to do this operation. Depending on what and how you're using your code, maybe you can calculate the value once, then update it each time you add a new value in `a` or `b`. So you only do the very expensive operation once, then updating the value is faster. That being said, the easiest solution would be to look into libraries such as NumPy and profit from the speed of C or Fortran code. What you're trying to do is inherently slow in Python.

Comment: @AndyS.C. My bad, generated the dict backwards. Should've been `dict(map(reversed, enumerate(alist)))`. Use the dict to look up indices (`adict[b]` instead of `alist.index(b)`).

Comment: One easy win would be to use a binary search when you calculate `position`. The function is called `bisect` in python. You could also possibly build up an index into `blist` to things speed up. `index` is a baaad function to use when performance matters it has linear time complexity.

Comment: @VincentSavard It doesn't matter if you write that code in C, C++ or assembly. O(n^2) is O(n^2) and when n= 10 millions the code **is** going to take a huge amount of time anyway.  However changing the algorithm to be O(nlog n) or O(n) will yield a *much bigger* improvement, independently of the language used.  I believe the `bisect` answer below will run orders of magnitude faster then the C translation of OPs code, and it only changes a few characters.

Comment: @Bakuriu It does matter and I'm curious why you think it doesn't. You're just talking about a completely different subject. Yes, improving the algorithm complexity is the way to go. It will still be faster by _orders of magnitude_ to run OP's algorithm in C than it would be in Python. That's just a fact, C is much better at looping through a list than Python.

Comment: @Bakuriu Forget my previous comment, I had mistakenly used Python 3 and thus the O(1) `range.index` instead of the O(n) `list.index`. Did the whole thing properly now and rewrote my answer.

Comment: @AndyS.C. In case you read my answer before, please read it again, I had made a huge mistake affecting the timing and rewrote the whole thing now.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using **binary search**. Makes it much faster, doesn't cost extra memory, and only requires a little change. Instead of `alist.index(b)`, simply use [`bisect_left(alist, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left).

In case your `blist` is sorted as well, you could also use a very simple incremental search, searching the current `b` not from the beginning of `alist` but from the index of the previous `b`.

Benchmarks with **Python 2.7.11** and lists containing 10 million and 8 million ints:

```
389700.01 seconds Andy_original (time estimated)
377100.01 seconds Andy_no_lists (time estimated)
     6.30 seconds Stefan_binary_search
     2.15 seconds Stefan_incremental_search
     3.57 seconds Stefan_incremental_search2
     1.21 seconds Jacquot_NumPy
    (0.74 seconds Stefan_only_search_no_distance)
```

Andy's originals would take about 4.5 days, so I only used every 100000-th entry of `blist` and scaled up. Binary search is much faster, incremental search is faster still, and NumPy beats them all, though they all take only seconds.

The last entry taking 0.74 seconds is my incremental search without the `distance = min(...)` line, so it's not comparable. But it shows that the search only takes about 34% of the total 2.15 seconds. So there's not much more that I could do, as now the `distance = min(...)` calculation is responsible for most of the time.

The results with **Python 3.5.1** are similar:

```
509819.56 seconds Andy_original (time estimated)
505257.32 seconds Andy_no_lists (time estimated)
     8.35 seconds Stefan_binary_search
     4.61 seconds Stefan_incremental_search
     4.53 seconds Stefan_incremental_search2
     1.39 seconds Jacquot_NumPy
    (1.45 seconds Stefan_only_search_no_distance)
```

The complete code with all versions and tests:

```
def Andy_original(alist, blist):
    for b in blist:
        position = alist.index(b)
        distance = min([b-alist[position-1], alist[position+1]-b])

def Andy_no_lists(alist, blist):
    for b in blist:
        position = alist.index(b)
        distance = min(b-alist[position-1], alist[position+1]-b)

from bisect import bisect_left
def Stefan_binary_search(alist, blist):
    for b in blist:
        position = bisect_left(alist, b)
        distance = min(b-alist[position-1], alist[position+1]-b)

def Stefan_incremental_search(alist, blist):
    position = 0
    for b in blist:
        while alist[position] < b:
            position += 1
        distance = min(b-alist[position-1], alist[position+1]-b)

def Stefan_incremental_search2(alist, blist):
    position = 0
    for b in blist:
        position = alist.index(b, position)
        distance = min(b-alist[position-1], alist[position+1]-b)

import numpy as np
def Jacquot_NumPy(alist, blist):

    a_array = np.asarray(alist)
    b_array = np.asarray(blist)

    a_index = np.searchsorted(a_array, b_array) # gives the indexes of the elements of b_array in a_array

    a_array_left = a_array[a_index - 1]
    a_array_right = a_array[a_index + 1]

    distance_left = np.abs(b_array - a_array_left)
    distance_right = np.abs(a_array_right - b_array)

    min_distance = np.min([distance_left, distance_right], axis=0)

def Stefan_only_search_no_distance(alist, blist):
    position = 0
    for b in blist:
        while alist[position] < b:
            position += 1

from time import time
alist = list(range(10000000))
blist = [i for i in alist[1:-1] if i % 5]
blist_small = blist[::100000]

for func in Andy_original, Andy_no_lists:
    t0 = time()
    func(alist, blist_small)
    t = time() - t0
    print('%9.2f seconds %s (time estimated)' % (t * 100000, func.__name__))

for func in Stefan_binary_search, Stefan_incremental_search, Stefan_incremental_search2, Jacquot_NumPy, Stefan_only_search_no_distance:
    t0 = time()
    func(alist, blist)
    t = time() - t0
    print('%9.2f seconds %s' % (t, func.__name__))
```

Comment: You just beat me to it.

Comment: @Jacquot 1) your numpy solution is still O(n^2) and *will* be slower with big arrays 2) Which sizes did you test? Bisecting is faster only for big sizes... you cannot take the OP sample input of 4 elements to test the performance. Generate 10 and 8 million lists and then profile with those.

Comment: Updated my benchmark (and my solution who wasn't completely right)  ; divided the time by 10 ; but in the end, what I'm using is just a vectorized Cython-implemented version of binary-search ;) Be delighted if you tried benchmarking with my last solution :)

Comment: @Jacquot I added a linear time solution and some benchmarks myself, see the end. Quite surprising. In what language is your binary-search implemented? If it's not Python, then I'd expect it to be much faster.

Comment: @Jacquot Are you able to use incremental search (my second solution) in NumPy? I don't know NumPy enough to even try.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann I had stupid typos in my updated solution, I assure you it works now ; my solution is also linear time, see how it scales with the benchmark inputs

Comment: NumPy gives a function for a task ; `numpy.searchsorted` is for returning indexes of array elements in a sorted arrays and uses binary search ; for this kind of tasks incremental search is not implemented as the function has to be of general use I guess

Comment: @Jacquot So your solution is **not** linear time, right?

Comment: I guess now it is : input_size:1 000 000 yields 53.2 ms and input_size:10 000 000 yields 591 ms

Comment: I guess that you inverted my solutions and their times ? I'd prefer you do not reference the old one as it was not correct for all inputs ; anyway it has been nice benchmarking with you :)

Comment: @Jacquot 591 vs 53 is significantly more than factor 10. Doesn't look linear. Looks like O(n log n) to me, which I'd also expect from it using binary search. Don't you think so?

Comment: 591/53 ~= 11.15 so nothing really significant for me, but I'm pretty sure you're right. Yes it should be O(n log n) i agree with you, but you clearly know more than me about algorithms ; if you're solution is linear, then for much larger inputs it would be better suited

Comment: @Jacquot Well, ok, it's not like the factor 100 that you'd expect from an O(n^2) solution like the OP's. But for n log n, you'd expect factor [11.67](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(10000000*log(10000000))%2F(1000000*log(1000000))), and the 11.15 is much closer to that than it is to factor 10.

Comment: @Jacquot Huge blunder, I apparently used Python 3 for testing and thus a `range` object instead of a `list`. Rewrote the whole thing now. Check again if you're interested, though the only real difference is that the original code's time increased a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the Numpy module for this kind of computing.

In your case, that would be (this is the long answer, could be factorized to be more efficient):

```
import numpy as np

alist = [1, 4, 30, 1000, 2000]
blist = [4, 30, 1000]

a_array = np.asarray(alist)
b_array = np.asarray(blist)

a_index = np.searchsorted(a_array, b_array) # gives the indexes of the elements of b_array in a_array

a_array_left = a_array[a_index - 1]
a_array_right = a_array[a_index + 1]

distance_left = np.abs(b_array - a_array_left)
distance_right = np.abs(a_array_right - b_array)

min_distance = np.min([distance_left, distance_right], axis=0)
```

It will not work if the first element of blist is the first of alist, same for the end. 
I guess :

```
alist = [b[0] - 1] + alist + [b[-1] + 1]
```

is a dirty workaround.

**Benchmark**
the "still running" may me my computer's fault..

```
alist = sorted(list(np.random.randint(0, 10000, 10000000)))
blist = sorted(list(alist[1000000:9000001]))
a_array = np.asarray(alist)
b_array = np.asarray(blist)
```

Vectorized solution

```
%%timeit
a_index = np.searchsorted(a_array, b_array)

a_array_left = a_array[a_index - 1]
a_array_right = a_array[a_index + 1]

min_distance = np.min([b_array - a_array_left, a_array_right - b_array], axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 591 ms per loop
```

Binary Search solution

```
%%timeit
for b in blist:
    position = bisect.bisect_left(alist, b)
    distance = min([b-alist[position-1],alist[position+1]-b])
Still running..
```

OP's solution

```
%%timeit
for b in blist:
    position=alist.index(b)
    distance=min([b-alist[position-1],alist[position+1]-b])
Still running..
```

**Smaller Inputs**

```
alist = sorted(list(np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000000)))
blist = sorted(list(alist[100000:900001]))
a_array = np.asarray(alist)
b_array = np.asarray(blist)
```

Vectorized solution

```
%%timeit
a_index = np.searchsorted(a_array, b_array)

a_array_left = a_array[a_index - 1]
a_array_right = a_array[a_index + 1]

min_distance = np.min([b_array - a_array_left, a_array_right - b_array], axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.2 ms per loop
```

Binary Search solution

```
%%timeit
for b in blist:
    position = bisect.bisect_left(alist, b)
    distance = min([b-alist[position-1],alist[position+1]-b])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.57 s per loop
```

OP's solution

```
%%timeit
for b in blist:
    position=alist.index(b)
    distance=min([b-alist[position-1],alist[position+1]-b])
Still running..
```

Comment: Please don't show misleading benchmarks. Use 10 million and 8 million elements, respectively.

Comment: **alist must be sorted!** Your benchmarks are useless because `alist` is not sorted!!!

Comment: In your benchmarks you should change `alist=[1, 4, 30, 1000, 2000]*10000` with something like `alist = sorted(list(range(1000)) * 10000)`

Comment: @Jacquot Your solution does not give correct results. I got `[  -26  -970 -1000]` while there should be `[3, 26, 970]`.

Comment: @Andy S. C : fixed ; as I did not choose sorted arrays, I have to add np.abs() but this way it works ;

Comment: Benchmark and solution fixed ; but i guess `np.searchsorted` is just a vectorized Cython-implemented version of binary-search

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann yeah two stupid typos, had mixed my previous and current solution ; fixed